# how can I active RTS(RS232) pin in C#

Tags: serial-port, handshake

I want to  send pulse to my electronic board with RS232 line
Can I use RTS pin ?(after that my board  get pulse and start to sending data to PC )
how can I  active this pin in C# ?

Comment: The SerialPort.RtsEnable property is not well hidden.  Surely you ought to describe what happened when you tried to use it.

Comment: 'I used   myport.DtrEnable = true; ' but I don't see any pulse on this pin

Comment: If you are testing with a cable then raising DTR will show up on CD or DSR.  If raising RTS and a cable the output will show up on CTS.  DTR and RTS aren't pulsed, they are on or off.

Comment: I need one pulse( Rising edge pulse) What's your suggestion for me?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
port.RtsEnable = true;
Thread.Sleep(1000); // ~1000 ms pulse width 
port.RtsEnable = false;
```

Be aware that the behavior of the RTS pin can be unexpected before opening the port (from my experience it's depending on your hardware, FTDI chips goes on/off several times on initializing).

Suggesting to use some real RS232 relay (which is very cheap) - for full and stable control over the voltage and the state.

Comment: Good answer, but IMHO I believe that "RTS goes on/off several times on initializing" is dependent on the user application code and how the [communication is configured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201(v=vs.85).aspx). With careful design, the RTS will not go high until the COM resource was successfully opened and RTS is actually set high.

Comment: Thanks for the information, can you tell if it's possible to get that deep using c#?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my call. I'm only familiar with the C/C++ way as in the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363201(v=vs.85).aspx), but I don't know what exactly is the behavior of the [Win32_SerialPort class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394413(v=vs.85).aspx). Maybe someone else with C# background can help.